# How to long poll amazon sqs service using boto?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, boto3, amazon-sqs

I have a sqs queue on amazon that have several consumer polling it.

Recently I found out that the `numberofEmptyReceives` is in the 10 millions, this means that I am being charge on those request.

The following is how I am consuming message

```
while True:
    for message in queue.receive_messages(AttributeNames=['All'], MaxNumberOfMessages=10):
```

I know there is `WaitTimeSeconds` option but the documentation seems to suggest it does not do long poll

> The duration (in seconds) for which the call waits for a message to arrive in the queue before returning.
>   If a message is available, the call returns sooner than WaitTimeSeconds . 
>   If no messages are available and the wait time expires, the call returns successfully with an empty list of messages.

Specifically

> If a message is available, the call returns sooner than WaitTimeSeconds .

From the above sentence it seems to suggest `boto3` still calls `sqs` to check if there is message or not.

What is the proper way to long poll using boto3 to avoid getting charge for request?

Is it as simple as setting `thread.sleep` ?

I also can't find the source code on [github](https://github.com/boto/boto3/search?q=receive_messages&type=Code)

Comment: There is no simple solution for this issue. Using SQS to trigger lambda for every message can be overkill if you have tons of individual batch messages overtime.  Increase the polling time may mean slow services response.  You need to make your own justification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just send a `WaitTimeSeconds` parameter (up to a maximum of 20 seconds) in your `receive_message` call. From the AWS documentation:

```
# Long poll for message on provided SQS queue
response = sqs.receive_message(
    QueueUrl=queue_url,
    AttributeNames=[
        'SentTimestamp'
    ],
    MaxNumberOfMessages=1,
    MessageAttributeNames=[
        'All'
    ],
    WaitTimeSeconds=20
)
```

If there is no message in the queue, then the call will wait up to `WaitTimeSeconds` for a message to appear. If a message appears before the time expires, the call will return that message right away.

See [Enabling Long Polling in Amazon SQS](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/sqs-example-long-polling.html) for more details.

You'd still be charged for the long-poll request. The cost saving is in performing one billable SQS action and waiting up to the long-poll timeout, where otherwise you might have had to perform two or three or more billable actions over the same period.

Comment: Sorry I am confused, `If a message appears before the time expires, the call will return that message right away.`  How is the above statement possible without continuous polling since sqs does not have the ability to push to my server? And if it does continuous polling why does it have less request than simply not wait for `WaitTimeSeconds`

Comment: Down deep, the API may be doing continuous polling. At about $0.40 per million requests after the first million requests for free, I've never had to verify. But, under the contract of long polling you aren't charged for that activity.